# jQuery Autocomplete Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, autocompletar

Estou usando [jQuery autocomplete](https://www.devbridge.com/sourcery/components/jquery-autocomplete/#) para pegar dados de um JSON e mostrá-los no como sugestões no formulário durante a digitação. Acontece que o JSON não está no formato esperado pelo plugin, então resolvi tentar transformá-lo num array, mas fica só nesse erro.

Meu código

```
var arr;
$(document).ready(function getClientedata(){
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '//jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) {
        for(var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
        var obj = response[i];
        arr = [
                { value: obj.name, data: obj.id },
        ];      console.log(arr);
      }
    },
    error: function(xhr, e, t){
        alert('Error');
    }
  });
  $('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
      lookup: arr,
      onSelect: function (suggestion) {
          alert('You selected: ' + suggestion.value + ', ' + suggestion.data);
      }
  });
});
```

Já deixei preparado um [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hy3qs80k/3/) tbm, pra quem quiser ver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O erro `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` pode ser no Ajax (antes do autocompleto), o que duvido um pouco, porque é um tanto quanto improvavel o ajax do jquery retornar `undefined` ou pode ser devido a variavel que você passou no **`lookup`**

Parece que tem 2 problemas o escopo da variavel `arr` pode estar afetando ela e você esta populando incorretamente o Array:

```
arr = [
        { value: obj.name, data: obj.id },
];
```

Isto só vai pegar o ultimo resultado, o correto deveria ser algo como:

```
$(document).ready(function getClientedata(){
    var arr = []; //Cria a array

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '//jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response) {
            for(var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                var obj = response[i];
                arr.push({ value: obj.name, data: obj.id }); //Adiciona item a array
            }
        },
        error: function(xhr, e, t){
            alert('Error');
        }
    });

    $('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
        lookup: arr,
        onSelect: function (suggestion) {
            alert('You selected: ' + suggestion.value + ', ' + suggestion.data);
        }
    });
});
```

Veja um exemplo funcionando (sem o ajax):

```js
$(document).ready(function getClientedata(){
    var arr = []; //Cria a array

    arr.push({ value: "foo", data: 1 });
    arr.push({ value: "bar", data: 2 });
    arr.push({ value: "baz", data: 3 });
    arr.push({ value: "stack", data: 4 });
    arr.push({ value: "overflow", data: 5 });

    $('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
        lookup: arr,
        onSelect: function (suggestion) {
            alert('You selected: ' + suggestion.value + ', ' + suggestion.data);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.devbridge-autocomplete/1.4.2/jquery.autocomplete.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="country" id="autocomplete">
```

### Maneira alternativa

A maneira alternativa é usar o **`callback`** do lookup, ficaria algo assim:

```
$(document).ready(function getClientedata(){
    $('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
        lookup: function (query, done) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '//jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(response) {
                    var result = { "suggestions": [] };

                    for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                        var obj = response[i];

                        // Adiciona item a array
                        result.suggestions.push({
                            value: obj.name, data: obj.id
                        });
                    }

                    done(result); //Envia a resposta "formatada" pro autocomplete
                },
                error: function(xhr, e, t){
                    alert('Error');
                }
            });

            done(result);
        },
        onSelect: function (suggestion) {
            alert('You selected: ' + suggestion.value + ', ' + suggestion.data);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Cara, muito obrigado, me salvou aqui!